# Simpler syntax for overloading function names

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overloading

In Haskell with the type families extension, this is perfectly legal ([ideone](http://ideone.com/RzMkM9)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family F a

data A = A Int
data B = B Double

type instance F A = Int
type instance F B = Double

class Get a where
  get :: a -> F a

instance Get A where
  get (A x) = x

instance Get B where
  get (B x) = x

main = print $ (get (A 3), get (B 2.0))
```

Basically I've defined two functions `get`.

One with type signature:

```
get :: A -> Int
```

And the second:

```
get :: B -> Double
```

However, there's a lot of cruft in the code above. What I'd like to be able to do is this:

```
get :: A -> Int
get (A x) = x

get :: B -> Double
get (B x) = x
```

I understand using this syntax exactly won't work, but is there any way I can get what I want to achieve without a dozen lines defining type instances and class instances? Considering first code works fine, I see no reason why the Haskell compiler can't this shorter code into the above anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
class Get a b | a -> b where
  get :: a -> b

instance Get A Int where
  ...
```

https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies

Okay, so it only got rid of type families. I don't think you can get rid of type classes, as they are *the* method of implementing overloading. Besides, without a class, you would not be able to express class constraints in types, e.g. you could not write this:

```
getPaired :: (Get a b, Get c d) => (a, c) -> (b, d)
```

Comment: I'm going to make this the answer. Two lines per definition, two lines to set up, does the job nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is applicable to your use case - your example is rather contrived. But you can use a GADT instead of type classes here:

```
data T a where 
  A :: Int -> T Int 
  B :: Double -> T Double 

get :: T a -> a
get (A x) = x
get (B x) = x
```

In general, there is no way to get the compiler to guess what code you want to write and write it for you. Such a compiler would obsolete a majority of programmers, I suspect, so we should all be glad it doesn't exist. I do agree that you are writing quite a lot to do very little, but perhaps that is a sign there is something wrong with your code, rather than a deficit in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data A = A Int
data B = B Double

class Get a where
    type F a
    get :: a -> F a

instance Get A where
    type F A = Int
    get (A x) = x

instance Get B where
    type F B = Double
    get (B x) = x

main = print (get (A 3), get (B 2.0))
```

It looks nicer to me, than functional dependencies.
All the stuff is described at https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families